# Hide children posts in loop with custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom taxonomy that acts like categories. Im using the following loop to show posts from this taxonomy:

```
$exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
                  'post_type' => 'cars',
                  'car_type' => 'large_cars',
                  'posts_per_page' => 100,
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'include_children' => false
                ) );

                    //* The Loop
                    if ( $exec_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

                          <?php

                        while ( $exec_query->have_posts() ): $exec_query->the_post();

                              get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'single-produkt' );

                        endwhile; ?>

                        <?php

                        //* Restore original Post Data
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }
```

This displays all posts that are posted in the taxonomy "Large cars".

But this taxonomy have children categories like "SUV", "Vans" and posts from this childs are also shown. I do not want to show this, but include_children does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, found a solution by first getting the ID's of the child categories and then exclude them from the WP_Query-array:

```
                $term_id = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy)->term_id;
                $taxonomy_name = $taxonomy;
                $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
                $exclude = "";

                foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
                    $term2 = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                    $exclude = $exclude . "" . $term2->term_id . ",";
                }
                $exclude = substr($exclude, 0, -1);

                 $args = array(
                             //Rest of you args go here
                            'tax_query' =>  array (
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, // My Custom Taxonomy
                                    'terms' => explode(',', $exclude), // My Taxonomy Term that I wanted to exclude
                                    'field' => 'id', // Whether I am passing term Slug or term ID
                                    'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Selection operator - use IN to include, NOT IN to exclude
                                ),
                            ),
                              'post_type' => $type,
                              $taxonomy  => $term,
                              'posts_per_page' => 100,
                              'order' => 'ASC',
                          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,you have to use include_children as below to remove the children taxonomies.

```
  $args = array(
             //Rest of you args go here
             'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'include_children' => false
                  )
              ),
              'post_type' => 'cars',
              'car_type' => 'large_cars',
              'posts_per_page' => 100,
              'order' => 'ASC'
          );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you, allthough when I add this part no posts are shown at all :/

Comment: Might it have something to do with that "large_cars" has a parent itself?

Comment: Taxonomies are a mess. Have toy tried this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449815/wordpress-how-can-i-exclude-posts-in-child-taxonomies-from-a-custom-taxonomy-qu

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, I'm looking into it right now. Tried copy/paste, but no difference. Not sure how to combine that with my loop?